# Execute a Sql script from powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL script to get the database size, i need to run it on 50 SQL servers each server has around 10 Databases and get a report for each database. how can I perform that using powershell.

So my question is how to execute a sql script remotely from poweshell and get the output on each database

This is the script i tried to use, i  found it on line and update it but it is not working

```
$dbservers=get-content "c:\powershell\list.txt"   
$Cre = Get-Credential -Credential xxxxxxxxxxxxx

ForEach-Object ($s in $dbservers)
 {
      [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')       | out-null
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $server
$dbs = $s.Databases
$dbs | SELECT Name -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object{
String]$database = $_
if (($database -ne "master") -and ($database -ne "tempdb") -and ($database -ne "msdb") -and ($database -ne "model"))  {
$ServerName = $dbservers
$DatabaseName = $database
$Query = "Create Table ##temp
     (
       ServerName nvarchar(250),
       DatabaseName sysname,
       Name sysname,
       physical_name nvarchar(500),
      size decimal (18,2),
      FreeSpace decimal (18,2)
          )   
        Exec sp_msforeachdb '
      Use [?];
      Insert Into ##temp (ServerName,DatabaseName, Name, physical_name, Size, FreeSpace)
      Select @@SERVERNAME ,DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName], Name,  physical_name,
       Cast(Cast(Round(cast(size as decimal) * 8.0/1024.0,2) as decimal(18,2)) as nvarchar) Size,

      From sys.database_files '

    Select * 
    From ##temp
     where DatabaseName not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb')
    drop table ##temp "

#Timeout parameters
 $QueryTimeout = 120
$ConnectionTimeout = 30

 #Action of connecting to the Database and executing the query and returning        results if there were any.
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated    Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerName, $DatabaseName,     $ConnectionTimeout
 $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
 $conn.Open()
 $cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query, $conn)
 $cmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
 $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
 $da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
 [void]$da.fill($ds)
 $conn.Close()
  $ds.Tables 
  } 
  } 
  }
```

i am getting this error

```
 The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection:    "Failed to connect to server ..".
  At C:\Powershell\datafile.ps1:10 char:1
   +  <<<< $dbs | SELECT Name -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object{
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

Comment: thanks for  looking at my question. May you tell me what the reason for getting negative point !!

Comment: Actually in this case i don't need to run it on each database .. i guess i can ignore the $Database variable

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  You've got to give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't run a query for a such tasks. powershell can access the database properties. I will give you the code to run on specific server, what you can do is to call inside your server loop and it will be ok.
If doesn't work just tell me i will send more customized way to do it. you can pipe my function to not include the system database.
I'M LAZY TO DO IT NOW.

```
Function Get-FSqlDBFileSizes([string]$serverInstance)
{
  [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
    try {


    $results = @()

    $server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $serverInstance

    foreach ($db in $server.Databases)
    {
        $dbname = $db.Name
        $fileGroups = $db.FileGroups
        $intRow=0
        foreach ($fg in $fileGroups) {
            If ($fg) {
                $intRow++

                $mdfInfo = $fg.Files | Select Name, FileName, size, UsedSpace
                $result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    DBName = $dbname
                    Name = $mdfInfo.Name
                    FileName = $mdfInfo.FileName
                    Size = ($mdfInfo.size / 1000)
                    UsedSpace = ($mdfInfo.UsedSpace / 1000)
                }
                $results += $result

                $logInfo = $db.LogFiles | Select Name, FileName, Size, UsedSpace
                $result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    DBName = $dbname
                    Name = $logInfo.Name
                    FileName = $logInfo.FileName
                    Size = ($logInfo.size / 1000)
                    UsedSpace = ($logInfo.UsedSpace / 1000)
                }
                $results += $result
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Output $results
}
catch [Exception] {
    Write-Error $Error[0]
    $err = $_.Exception
    while ( $err.InnerException ) {
        $err = $err.InnerException
        Write-Output $err.Message
    }
}
}
```

I'm going to lunch anything replay i will help you as much as i can.